# Check Number of Slots at any given time big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way to check how many slots are available at a particular time during the day in bigquery ?

We use flat pricing model, I want to execute the queries at that time, where there are maximum number of slots available

Comment: Have you tried to use GCP [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs) for this purpose, based on the Bigquery [Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigquery)  there are some metrics available for [visualization](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#metrics)(charts/alerts), thus I assume you can have a Bigquery slot allocation picture at any time. Does it answer your question or you have more concise doubt?

Comment: yes , that helps but that is quite inconsistent in our case,  what I want is any SQL query running query every 10 min or python script that check number of slots available.
I'm sure this would INFORMATION_SCHEMA table would be definitely give us some results.

Comment: Bigquery offers a dedicated metadata for slot [reservations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-tasks#assign_my_prod_project_to_prod_reservation) within particular `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-reservations). Have you tried to use it? Does it match you need?